# Count rows added today, yesterday...and other times

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I was given good direction to solve a problem today from here but I got stuck in trying to follow this direction.

I would like to retrieve a `count` for all rows from a table for the past `30 days` using my `date field`. I populate these fields using `now()` and they are in the format `Y-m-d h:i:s`.

- I need a `count` for the rows added
  today, yesterday, 3 days ago...etc
- I guess I can then use the above to
  get a count for each months?
- Finally a `count` for the year, year
  before etc using the months as total?

I was hoping not to specify dates in my query and for the query to just be generic and work out counts relative to today. I was hoping also I could do it accurately too by taking into consideration different months have different number of days.

How can I get this `count` using **just SQL**? I then can use the result set as an array and parse this with `PHP`.

Comment: hmm, why just SQL?  why not put some of that logic in your application code?

Comment: I was hoping it would be easier and more efficient at the database query level, isn't it?

Comment: Read the MySql date time functions and a bit of creativity. This should do the trick.

Comment: Abs, it's ALWAYS more efficient to work with data in the database. Even if you do it in a procedural way. @jonstjohn, if there were a million message you'd send the all to the app, instead of just the results? {I Cringe at your sight}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Number of records inserted yesterday:

```
select count(*) from mytable where date(myfield)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
```

For the year:

```
select count(*) from mytable where year(myfield)=year(now());
```

And so on...

Comment: Wait, Do you want it to be cumulative? Doesn't make sense to me. How many messages set yesterday, should include how many I sent today. would you be more clear?

Comment: You can make it cumulative by changing = by >=, but I guess you know it.

Answer (score 2):

Look into MySQLs [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function it will give you what your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your database structure looks like, but you can probably achieve what you want using `GROUP BY`:

To aggregate by day:

```
SELECT date(my_date_field) d, count(*) c FROM tbl
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d
```

To aggregate by month:

```
SELECT year(my_date_field) y, month(my_date_field) m, count(*) c FROM tbl
GROUP BY y, m
ORDER BY y, m
```

To aggregate by year, you can simply remove the month parameter from the sample above.

If you want to `limit` the result to specifics you can use `WHERE` directly on `my_date_field` or `HAVING` on d, y or m. Use `DATE_SUB` to calculate the date relative to the current.

Answer (score 0):

Look into DATEDIFF... I'm not sure of the exact syntax with mysql, but it should end up being someing similar to:

```
select * from Table WHERE datediff(StartDate, Today) < DaySpan
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution based on grouping by date, month and year:

```
-- Testing data
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE(ID INT, AddDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TestTable
SELECT 1, '2009-03-04 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-05-14 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-05-14 14:58:02' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-05-24 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-05-24 14:58:02' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-05-24 14:58:03' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-07-04 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-09-04 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-01-04 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-03-04 14:58:01' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-03-04 14:58:02'

-- MySQL Answer
-- for each day
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH_DAY, AddDate), COUNT(ID) FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH_DAY, AddDate)
-- for each month
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH, AddDate), COUNT(ID) FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH, AddDate)
-- for each year
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR, AddDate), COUNT(ID) FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR, AddDate)

-- SQL Answer
-- for each day
SELECT dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, AddDate)+0, 0), COUNT(ID) 
FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, AddDate)+0, 0)
-- for each month
SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, AddDate)+0, 0), COUNT(ID) 
FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, AddDate)+0, 0)
-- for each year
SELECT dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, AddDate)+0, 0), COUNT(ID) 
FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, AddDate)+0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers explicitly mention how to get the date for today:

```
select count(*) from transactions where date(created_at)=date(now());
```

For completeness there's also the following that *seems* to be functionally equivalent:

```
SELECT count(*) AS today 
FROM transactions 
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE` stands for **cur**rent **date** (i.e. today starting from 00:00 midnight rather than the last 24 hours), but `now()` also seems to use the same definition so at least in my tests there was no real difference between the commands.