# Creating MySQL query to count number of rows with differences

Tags: mysql, sql

my first ever attempt at using MySQL so forgive me if what I'm asking is obvious.

I run the following query to return all of the records in my table (each one representing a listing and it's price)

```
SELECT * FROM property_db.property_history
```

The table is in the format like so:

| address | price | date_created | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Address 1 | £400,000 | 2022/01/01 | new data |
| Address 2 | £350,000 | 2022/02/02 | new data |
| Address 1 | £300,000 | 2022/03/03 | update data |
| Address 3 | £300,000 | 2022/03/06 | new data |
| Address 1 | £250,000 | 2022/10/03 | update data |
| Address 2 | £150,000 | 2022/10/03 | update data |

I'd like to be able to query the database and find out how many rows have been updated (status of `update data`) on a given date.

So in the case above, I can see that that on the date: 2022/10/03 - they were 2 price updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count rows added today, yesterday...and other times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611402/count-rows-added-today-yesterday-and-other-times)

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you an answer you provided at the bottom of the question.  You can use this as a template to adapt your specific use case.

> So in the case above, I can see that that on the date: 2022/10/03 -
> they were 2 price updates.

```
SELECT date_created, count(*) status_count 
FROM property_db.property_history
WHERE status = 'updated data' AND date_created = '2022/10/03'
GROUP BY date_created
```